# How could you detect roundoff error without running the program?

Tags: java

I found this question on a practice test for a computer science class:

```
double num1 = 10;
double num2 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    num2 += .2;
}

System.out.println(num1 == num2);
System.out.println(num1 / num2 == 1);
System.out.println(num1 - num2 == 0);
```

a)  true true true
b)  true false false
c)  false true false
d)  false false true
e)  false false false

The correct answer was e. If you print out `num2` at the end, you get `9.999999999999996`. How could I know this?

Comment: You should always expect rounding errors when working with floating-point values.

Comment: You have to know that 0.2 can't be expressed exactly as a double, therefore, adding it 50 times will surely have rounding errors

Comment: @JuanMendes, however, adding it 41 times does not. How can I know this?

Comment: Read this: http://floating-point-gui.de/ and if you want a really detailed article, read this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: You can't. This is (IMHO) rather poot way your teacher is telling you that floating point arithmetics is not precise. The only way to know the answer is to know that floating points are not precise and assuming that the teacher wrote this example in shuch way it exposes this imprecission. In precise world `50 * 0.2 = 10` and all three expressions evaluate to `true`. In programming world `50 * 0.2 != 10` and all three expressions evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.2 cannot be exactly represented as an [IEEE 745](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating point number, which is what Java uses for float and double. The only non-integral floating point numbers that can be exactly represented are powers of two, for example:

- 0.5 `1/2`
- 0.25 `1/4`
- 0.75 `3/4`
- 0.1875 `3/16`

There is no way to represent 0.2 (which is `2/10` or `1/5`) as a double exactly. The test maker expects you to know that.

0.2 (decimal) is 0.0011001100110011... in binary (0011, or `3/16` repeating endlessly).

(There's no way to represent `1/3` or `1/7` exactly in decimal digits, which is the same problem.)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate what the value will be by using the IEEE 754 floating point standard.

The Java specification for the 'double' primitive type is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)